# Evaluating a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have a function that returns a numpy array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import derivative
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
f = x**2 + y **2
def grad(f):
    exp = sp.expand(f)
    dfdx = sp.diff(exp,x)
    dfdy = sp.diff(exp,y)
    global grad
    Df = np.array([dfdx,dfdy])
    return Df
```

I'm using the variable `Df` in another function and do some computations with it.

As you may have guessed, the results come out including `x` and `y`. However, I need the results to be evaluated each time with the initial values I choose for `x` and `y` instead of the symbols.

I was wondering if there was something like the `.subs()` in sympy but works on a numpy array rather than a function????

Comment: Why are you using `numpy` at all?  Stick with `sympy`

Comment: Your `Df` is an object dtype array (look at `Df.dtype`).  That's basically the same as the list `[dfdx, dfdy]`.  An math on such an array delegates the action to the methods of the elements.  So that math is hit-or-miss and not fast.  `numpy` does not have "knowledge" of `sympy` objects.

Comment: I'm using numpy for the entire code and somehow thought I should get this to work with it as well instead of thinking of @JohanC said. thanks, everyone. My way of thinking was all wrong from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sympy and numpy are two separate worlds, that aren't easy to bring together.

With sympy's lambdify, sympy expressions can be made to work on numpy arguments.  When arrays are used as arguments, they all need to be 1D and of the same size. The function `np_grad_1` below is how it works standard. It returns an array with two subarrays.

To get your desired functionality, a wrapper can take a 2D numpy input and convert the result back to a 2D numpy array:

```py
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
f = x ** 2 + y ** 2

def grad(f, x, y):
    exp = sp.expand(f)
    dfdx = sp.diff(exp, x)
    dfdy = sp.diff(exp, y)
    return [dfdx, dfdy]

np_grad_1 = sp.lambdify([x, y], grad(f, x, y))
np_grad_2 = lambda points: np.array(np_grad_1(points[:, 0], points[:, 1])).T

points = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (5, 2))

np_grad_1(points[:, 0], points[:, 1]) # returns an array with 2 subarrays
np_grad_2(points) # returns an Nx2 array
```

Comment: I was trying to use lambdify at first but somehow missed it up !. this makes tthings a alot clear for me. Thanks, I can fix quite a lot portion in my code.

Comment: oh, I'm relatively new to StackOverflow, how do I do that?

Comment: Yup I think i just found out how